# React native watchman not detecting changes

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm using react native to build my IOS project & was able to run the project in the IOS simulator.

I'm using watchman to detect changes in the file but, for some reason, whenever there is CSS missing in my REACT component, it throws a general error rather than missing CSS element-

**`Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`**

Is it possible to setup watchman to display the actual error.

OS - MAC

Answer (score 1):

Need to allow disk permission to watchman from System Preferences. Follow the steps:

Open System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Full Disk Access -> and mark check on watchman with admin access